# Zend framework facebook redirect URL to canvas application URL

Tags: php, zend-framework, facebook

I am currently developing a facebook canvas (iframe) based application. Is there any way to get Zend framework to output URLs like this:

```
http://app.facebook.com/appName/controller/action
```

intead of getting

```
http://www.domain.com/controller/action ?
```

It is not so important because due to iframe based app everything is working fine, but I'd like to provide better user experince and getting the url

```
http://app.facebook.com/appName/
```

is not user friendly at all. Probably the solution is very easy but I am completely "stack". The application is devided to modules so I can change sth in Boostrap.php which is probably to hold the solution underneath my nose but I can not see it..:-/

**EDIT:**
Maybe i did not expressed it as I should have. The problem is not within facebook. The problem is in **zend itself**. It outputs the **original application** (e.g. myapp.example.com) URL and I want it to output http://app.facebook.com/myapp

Thanks in advance.

Lukas

Comment: I am not sure if did understand it correctly but i guess you are looking to create DNS CNAME Record or as it called alias , so if you did an alias you wouldn't need to change any thing in your ZF app , for example if you create CNAME record of google.com with the name "blahblah.com" , you would be able to browse google.com with that RECORD .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve this issue. So for fellow developers I am posting here my solution.

The soulition is to be honest a bit complicated but:

```
Use Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname
```

The example of usage can be found in http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html the and then Chain it with classic route like:

```
$hostnameRoute = new
    Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname(
                     ':username.users.example.com',
                     array(       
                  'controller' => 'profile',
                  'action'     => 'userinfo'
              )
      );
$plainPathRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static('');
$router->addRoute('user', $hostnameRoute->chain($plainPathRoute);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is but Facebook already maps the URLs it receives to your application.

For example if your canvas URL is set to `http://domain.com/` and a user goes into `http://apps.facebook.com/appName/controller` it will get mapped to `http://domain.com/controller` by Facebook.

It works this way for both canvas/fbml and iframe applications.

To make Zend Framework generate URLs with an alternate base (ie: `http://apps.facebook.com/appName`) you can do this in your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initBaseUrl() {        
    $front  = $this->getResource('frontcontroller');
    $front->setBaseUrl('http://apps.facebook.com/appName/');
}
```

If you are not using the bootstrap, you can get an instance of your front controller in an alternate way and do this:

```
    $front  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->setBaseUrl('http://apps.facebook.com/appName/');
```

Comment: Maybe i did not expressed it as I should have. The problem is not within facebook. The problem is in zend itself. It outputs the original application (e.g. myapp.example.com) URL and I want it to output http://app.facebook.com/myapp

Comment: Hi,thanks very much - I will post my final code but there another problem has occured. The application now says "Invallid controller specified" and I can not tell why :-(

Comment: Hi, I have been experimenting with the code that you have provided with poor results. The URL is still intact and point to the original server (not the facebook app canvas page). I have also discovered that the setBaseUrl method is (according to the Zedn Api page) used for getting absolute path to the document root than to generate links :-/.

Comment: If you are using the view helper, 'url', to generate your links, it will utilize the baseUrlPath and prepend it to all links generated.

Comment: Ah, okey. I will give it a try during the weekend and I'll let you know. Thanks for your time.